# Convergence of recursive sequence given Uo

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

Please how could I possibly show that the sequence defined by

$U_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} (U_n + \frac{a}{U_n})$ converges
Given that $U_0 > 0$ and $a>0$

I have calculated $\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}$ which is positive but $U_{n+1}-U_n$ doesn't yield any result and i can't show it is bounded.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First note that if $u_0>0$ and $a>0$, then it is easy to show that
$$u_n>0$$
Then by AM-GM we have
$$u_{n+1} =\frac{1}{2}\left(u_n+\frac{a}{u_n}\right) \ge \sqrt{u_n\frac{a}{u_n}}=\sqrt{a}$$

Hence
$$u_{n+1}-u_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a}{u_n}-u_n\right)\le\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a}}-\sqrt{a}\right)=0$$

Hence, $u_n$ is decreasing and bounded from below. Therefore it converges.

After proving that it converges, one can obtain the limit by taking limit on both sides of the recursion relation, which gives
$$l=\frac{1}{2}\left(l+\frac{a}{l}\right)$$
$$l^2=a$$
$$l=\sqrt{a}$$
where the negative root is rejected since the it is a positive sequence.

Comment: Please can you be more explicit on how you used AM-GM

Answer (score 1):

If the {$u_{n}$} sequence tends to some u then it must be $u={1\over2}(u+{a\over u})$ which results in $u=\pm\sqrt a$ but this is very imprecise. Embarking on this and knowing that $u_{n+1}={1\over2}(u_{n}+{a\over u_{n}})={\sqrt a\over2}({{u_n\over\sqrt a}+{\sqrt a \over u_{n}})}>\sqrt a$ the limit must probably be $\sqrt a$,therefore by defining error function $e_{n}=u_{n}-\sqrt a$ we get $e_{n+1}={1\over2}(e_{n}+{a\over u_{n}}-\sqrt a)$. Since $u_{n}>\sqrt a$ we have ${a\over u_{n}}-\sqrt a<0$ and $e_{n+1}<{1\over2}e_{n}$ which tends to zero and the sequence is convergent to $\sqrt a$